# Python Openpyxl VLOOKUP from other file

Tags: python, file, openpyxl

I have 2 files, lets say 't1.xlsx' and 't2.xlsx'.

What i want to do is to do the VLOOKUP fucntion inside the t1 file using the data from t2 file.

I try to paste

```
"sheet["O2"].value = "=VLOOKUP(C:C;'C:\\Users\\KKK\\Desktop\\sheets\\excellent\\
[t2.xlsx]baza'!$A$2:$AI$10480;25;0)"
```

where `baza` is a sheet name, but sadly when i try open the file it says it can not be open due to the error and offers me repairing tool.

rest of the code:

```
import openpyxl


wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('t1.xlsx')
sheets = wb.get_sheet_names()
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

[VLOOKUP STUFF FROM BEFORE]

wb.save("t1.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

With more complicated formulae you should always check the syntax in the XML because they are often stored differently than they appear in Excel. This is covered in the [documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#using-formulae). You might be okay simply using a comma as a separator but I suspect you'll also have change the path of the file and use a Python raw string (the `r` prefix).